# Adding if Catchpa pass in my submit form please

Tags: php, captcha

Good day, I have been stuck on this for the last few days and would really appreciate any help! I am trying to add my Catchpa form in the requirement to be able to submit my quiz. So far, I only figured out that they require to fill their name, email and form to send, but I would also like the Catchpa to be a requirement. Would really appreciate any help!

```
<?php
// BEGIN CONFIGURATION ////////////////////////////////////////////////
define('EMAIL_TO', 'test@hotmail.com');
define('EMAIL_SUBJECT', 'Test Subject');
// END CONFIGURATION ////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    function CheckCaptcha($userResponse) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
        'secret' => '6LfMz2EUAAAAAF5VwFWDGRfsyj6Ik0ngJrhHKK3w',
        'response' => $userResponse
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($res, true);
    }
    // Call the function CheckCaptcha
    $result = CheckCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    if ($result['success']) {
        //If the user has checked the Captcha box
        $msg = "<div class='error'>Captcha verified Successfully.</div>";
    } else {
        // If the CAPTCHA box wasn't checked
        $msg = "<div class='error'>Captcha failed.</div>";
    }
}
if ($_POST) {
    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $message  = $_POST['message'];
    // Error handling - This is where I would like to add also the Catchpa requirement before they can submit it.
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)){
        $msg = "<div class='error'>One or more fields is blank.</div>";
    } else if (!$email == '' && (!strstr($email, '@') || !strstr($email, '.'))) {
        $msg = "<div class='error'>Your email address is not formatted correctly.</div>";
    }
    // Build email headers
    else {
        $headers = "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        // Build email body
        $body = '
            <html><body>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr><td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; padding:10px;" colspan="2">' . $email_subject . '</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top" style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;" valign="top"><b>Name:</b></td><td style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;">' . $name . ' (' . $email . ')</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top" style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;" valign="top"><b>Message:</b></td><td style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;">' . $message . '</td></tr>
            </table>
            </body></html>';
        // Send the email, reset text boxes on form, and show success message
        mail(EMAIL_TO, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $body, $headers);
        $name    = '';
        $email   = '';
        $message = '';
        $msg     = "<div class='success'>Thank you, we will get back to you as soon as we can!</div>";
    }
}
?>
<?php echo $msg; ?>
<form method="post">
<p class="form-group">Name:<br><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" required value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></p>
<p class="form-group">Email:<br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></p>
<p class="form-group">Message:<br><textarea name="message" class="form-control" required rows="5" cols="40" />
<?php echo $message; ?>
</textarea>
</p>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfMz2EUAAAAANpK7eWaiCxYq6QcPH8_XvKdIRyK"></div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: @user3783243 thank you so much, you're an angle! Would you mind showing me how it would look, just to make sure I have it correct please?

Comment: Moved to an answer.

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you so so much!! <3

Answer (score 0):

Your CAPTCHA condition is unrelated to the rest of the application's code.

I think something like this would be a good starting point for you. This requires the CAPTCHA's response be `success` for the mail to send, and for other error checks to fire. This also adds a check to see if the form has been submitted.

```
<?php
// BEGIN CONFIGURATION ////////////////////////////////////////////////
define('EMAIL_TO', 'test@hotmail.com');
define('EMAIL_SUBJECT', 'Test Subject');
// END CONFIGURATION ////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Call the function CheckCaptcha
    $result = CheckCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    if ($result['success']) {
        //If the user has checked the Captcha box
        $msg = "<div class='error'>Captcha verified Successfully.</div>";
        $name     = $_POST['name'];
        $email    = $_POST['email'];
        $message  = $_POST['message'];
        // Error handling - This is where I would like to add also the Catchpa requirement before they can submit it.
        if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)){
            $msg = "<div class='error'>One or more fields is blank.</div>";
        } else if (!$email == '' && (!strstr($email, '@') || !strstr($email, '.'))) {
            $msg = "<div class='error'>Your email address is not formatted correctly.</div>";
        } else {
            $headers = "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            // Build email body
            $body = '
                <html><body>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                <tr><td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; padding:10px;" colspan="2">' . $email_subject . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top" style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;" valign="top"><b>Name:</b></td><td style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;">' . $name . ' (' . $email . ')</td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top" style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;" valign="top"><b>Message:</b></td><td style="padding:10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;">' . $message . '</td></tr>
                </table>
                </body></html>';
            // Send the email, reset text boxes on form, and show success message
            mail(EMAIL_TO, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $body, $headers);
            $name    = '';
            $email   = '';
            $message = '';
            $msg     = "<div class='success'>Thank you, we will get back to you as soon as we can!</div>";
        }
    } else {
        // If the CAPTCHA box wasn't checked
        $msg = "<div class='error'>Captcha failed.</div>";
    }
} else {
    $msg = 'Form hasnt been submitted';
}
echo $msg;
?>
<form method="post">
    <p class="form-group">Name:<br><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" required value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></p>
    <p class="form-group">Email:<br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></p>
    <p class="form-group">Message:<br><textarea name="message" class="form-control" required rows="5" cols="40" />
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        </textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfMz2EUAAAAANpK7eWaiCxYq6QcPH8_XvKdIRyK"></div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php
    function CheckCaptcha($userResponse) {
        return array('success' => 1);
    }
?>
```

Your code also is open to header injections and XSS injections. You should look into those additionally.